# Setting default printer

Tags: php

In my php page when i click on button, I should print both receipts and application form. Receipt is printing in default printer and I have to send app form to another printer. Is this possible ?. Where I have to set the printer and How?. Pls guide me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using javascript's print method? As i think, you can achieve the objective by some javascript code and some timeouts. But it needs your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is out of PHP scope. 
It depends on settings in Operating System where Browser exists.